# What is the purpose of this.someFunction.call(this, param);

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've come across some code that has this sort of pattern in numerous places:

```
this.someFunction.call(this, param);
```

but it seems to me just a more verbose way of typing

```
this.someFunction(param)
```

The pattern sometimes appears inside a function which is provided as a callback. It happens to use Backbone, in case that's relevant. Something like this:

```
Backbone.View.extend({
    // other stuff ...

    someFunction: function(param) {
        // ...
    },
    anotherFunction: function() {
        this.collection.on("some_event", function() {
            this.someFunction.call(this, param);
        });
    }
});
```

Does the pattern actually have an effect that isn't the equivalent of `this.someFunction(param)` or was someone just nervous about the closure not capturing the correct `this`?

Thanks for any insights!

Comment: *"or was someone just nervous about the closure not capturing the correct `this`"* `this` is a special value inside functions and is not affected by scope. (exception: ES6 arrow functions). I don't see a reason here to prefer `.call` over a normal function call.

Comment: Both are equivalent probably some kind of coding convention.
Scripts are also obfuscated pretty often.

Comment: note that using call() adds some overhead and slows down execution, which is especially apparent in loops. the code could actually be written as 
`this.collection.on("some_event",  this.someFunction.bind(this, param));`which locks _this_ ahead of time, which can be faster than call(). although, depending on how backbone uses _this_, you might need to duplicate the bound value in anotherFunction() to have the right _this_ at that time.

Comment: Are you sure that `call` is being used in the real code rather than `apply`? If `param` was an array (or array-like object such as `arguments`) and `apply` was being used then it would make sense.

Comment: @muistooshort yep, I'm sure it's `call`, I had a feeling someone would ask that though :)

Comment: `param` in some cases is actually just a string, `this.someFunction.call(this, "a string");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the pattern actually have an effect that isn't the equivalent of `this.someFunction(param)`?

No, they are indeed the same. Assuming that `this.someFunction` is a function that inherits `.call` from `Function.prototype` (but that's nit-picking).

Looks like someone was overcautious, or the code is a remains of something that did not use `this` twice. Or maybe the author was aware of the [`this`-context-in-callbacks issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572) but failed to handle it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reasons to use such way of function call in code you provided. Here is better to use direct function call like this (if you need no modification with arguments)

```
this.collection.on("some_event", this.someFunction, this);
```

or

```
this.collection.on("some_event", function() {
    this.someFunction(//some modified args)
}, this);
```

And let me provide the example of proper usage of `.call`. Sure u've seen this:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
```

As `arguments` is not an array, we can 'borrow' Array method to operate with `arguments`. If you will try to call `slice` on `arguments` you will get an error